# Cron job for every weekday at 6 am

Tags: cron

I was wondering if anyone knew how to create a cron job that runs from monday to friday at 6am.

I am using gitlab CI, quickly looked at the example syntax and am not exactly sure how to limit it to occur from monday to friday.

Comment: You can use [this](https://crontab.guru/#0_6_*_*_1-5) for better understanding of cron expression

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure what about gitlab CI, but cron syntax is minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week, meaning job which should run every week day from 6am is

```
0 6 * * 1-5
```